# No se puede encontrar el tipo o espacio en los nombres de MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql

Los datos introducidos se deben registraren una base de datos, he visto videos sobre aquel tema pero al declarar la conexión me marca error:

```
No se puede encontrar el tipo o espacio en los nombres de MySqlConnection
```

¿Hace falta crear tablas en MySql Workbench?

```
///
    public partial class frmPrincipal : Form
    {
        public static MySqlConnection conexion;
        private string servidor;
        private string BD;
        private string usuario;
        private string clave;

        public frmPrincipal()
        {
            //
            // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer support.
            //
                InitializeComponent();

 servidor = "localhost";
 BD = "concierto";
            usuario = "root";
            clave = "";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + servidor + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            BD + ";" + "UID=" + usuario + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + clave + ";" + "Allow Zero Datetime =True" + ";" + "Convert Zero Datetime=True" + ";" +"Persist Security Info=True" + ";";

 conexion = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);

        }
```

Comment: Me parece que te falta un using al inicio de tu archivo, algo como `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;`. Comenta cómo te fue.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ver este ejemplo de conexion a Mysql con C#

```
 

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

   String connectionString = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;";
// Tu consulta en SQL
string query = "SELECT * FROM user";

// Prepara la conexión
MySqlConnection databaseConnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
MySqlCommand commandDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, databaseConnection);
commandDatabase.CommandTimeout = 60;
MySqlDataReader reader;

// A consultar !
try
{
    // Abre la base de datos
    databaseConnection.Open();

    // Ejecuta la consultas
    reader = commandDatabase.ExecuteReader();

    // Hasta el momento todo bien, es decir datos obtenidos

    // IMPORTANTE :#
    // Si tu consulta retorna un resultado, usa el siguiente proceso para obtener datos

    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // En nuestra base de datos, el array contiene:  ID 0, FIRST_NAME 1,LAST_NAME 2, ADDRESS 3
            // Hacer algo con cada fila obtenida
            string[] row = { reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2), reader.GetString(3) };
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No se encontraron datos.");
    }

    // Cerrar la conexión
    databaseConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Mostrar cualquier excepción
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente tenes que descargara el conector de MySQL para .NET [Download Connector/NET](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) Luego agregar la referencia(dll) a tu proyecto

y para tu codigo arias algo asi.

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=test;")
{
        conn.Open();//abrimos conexion
    MessageBox.Show("Conexion Establecida");    
    //tu demas codigo

}
```